# What is "is not a (visible) constructor field name" mean?

Tags: haskell

```
changecolour :: SquareWorld -> SquareWorld 
changecolour squareWorld =
    let 
    old_cell = theWorld squareWorld
    old_cellstate = cellState old_cell
    new_cellstate =nextCellState (old_cellstate (x : xs))
    new_cell = old_cell { old_cellstate = new_cellstate}
    newsquareWorld = squareWorld { old_cell = new_cell}
    in
    newsquareWorld

data Cell = Cell {cellPosition :: Coord, cellState :: CellState}
  deriving (Show, Eq)

nextCellState :: CellState -> CellState
nextCellState (CellState (_ :< xs)) = CellState xs

data SquareWorld = SquareWorld { theAnt :: Ant, theWorld :: [Cell]}
  deriving Show
```

The error message is :

> [12 of 14] Compiling StudentSources.LangtonsAnt ( src/StudentSources/LangtonsAnt.hs, build/x86_64/StudentSources/LangtonsAnt.o )
>
> src/StudentSources/LangtonsAnt.hs:154:50: Not in scope: ‘x’
>
> src/StudentSources/LangtonsAnt.hs:154:54: Not in scope: ‘xs’
>
> src/StudentSources/LangtonsAnt.hs:155:27:
>       ‘old_cellstate’ is not a (visible) constructor field name
>
> src/StudentSources/LangtonsAnt.hs:156:36:
>       ‘old_cell’ is not a (visible) constructor field name

**What should i do ?**

Answer (score 1):

```
new_cell = old_cell { old_cellstate = new_cellstate}
```

should be

```
new_cell = old_cell { cellState = new_cellstate}
```

You have to use the *name* of the field on the left of the `=` sign, not the previous value of said field. The name of the field is the one which was used in the `data T = K { fieldName :: Type , ... }` declaration.

There is a similar issue for `squareWorld`.

Comment: Thanks a lot about the answer of constructor field name. It's solved now.

Comment: But may i ask for a solution of the "not in scope: "x"" ?

Comment: @JonathanZhuang `x` was not declared at all... I'm not sure about what your are trying to achieve with that line.